# Retrofit: send multidimensional array / or nested hash in GET query

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to make a GET request to `/realties` path with some filtering parameters added to that request. Parameters may look like this:

```
?filter[num_rooms]=2&filter[region_coordinates][0]=[50,65]&filter[region_coordinates][1]=[51,62]
```

I can't find a way to send such nested parameters with Retrofit @GET request. I found that I can send only a Map of strings: `@QueryMap Map<String,String>`

Comment: I don't understand what do you exactly mean but if you want to define your params in json you have to use POST method

Comment: I updated my answer. I need to make a GET request, not POST.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same problem.